# Regex not to give overflow error

Tags: java, regex

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "Shyam and you. You are 2.3 km away from home. Lakshmi and you. Ram and you. You are Mike. ";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                "\\s*((?:[^\\.]|(?:\\w+\\.)+\\w)*are.*?)(?:\\.\\s|\\.$)",
                Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
You are 2.3 km away from home. 

You are Mike.
```

I am getting the expected output on executing the code above.
But the problem is when testing the same regex with some greater string , its showing overflow error.
I searched about the same and came to know that alternation like (A|B)* in the regular expression causes the problem.
Is there any way solve this issue?
Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that actually demonstrates the problem, and describe the *exact* problem you're seeing (stack trace if it's an error, or else tell us the exact incorrect output). What is your regex even *supposed* to do? What is your expected output for this "greater string"? Saying, in essence, "sometimes this doesn't work" doesn't give anyone enough information to help you.

Comment: *"when testing the same regex with some greater string"* How long of a string, exactly?

Comment: i tried a string of length 2800. It resulted in an error
[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Unknown Source)...]

I cant post that string. Because it exceeds the maximum character length which is allowed to be posted.

Comment: @user2722117 don't post such crucial informations in comment but include it in your question using [[edit]] option.

Comment: Is it possible for you to link file with example data that we could use to reproduce your error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to refactor your regex to avoid backtracking. Can you try out this regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?>[^.]|(?:\\w+\\.)+\\w)+\\sare\\s.*?(?>\\.\\s|\\.$)",
                  Pattern.DOTALL);
```

`(?>group)` is called **Atomic Grouping**.

As per: http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html

#### Atomic Grouping

> An atomic group is a group that, when the regex engine exits from it,
>   **`automatically throws away all backtracking positions remembered by any
>   tokens inside the group`**. Atomic groups are non-capturing. The syntax
>   is `(?>group)`.

Answer (score 1):

As Pshemo wisely pointed out in a comment, your problem is likely a result of [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) (due to all those nested quantifiers), rather than anything to do with length of the input String. That link above provides a very good example of why you can get `StackOverflowErrors` even with short input strings and simple-seeming regular expressions.

In brief, what it means is that in certain situations, the pattern matcher can take an exponential number of steps (compared to the length of the input) to determine a match/no-match. When this happens, the stack "overflows" because the pattern-matching recursion goes too deep. It's especially common with nested quantifiers, like the `(x+x+)+y` in the link above, or (one of several examples) `((?:\\w+\\.)+\\w)*` in your pattern.

If you explain what you're trying to write a regex for, it's very likely that we can help you come up with one that doesn't blow up if you give it unlucky or malicious input.

Given your comment on the requirements, you can do this with *way* less of a headache if you avoid using regular expressions at all. Just split the input around the delimiter (in your case, `". "`) and then search each result for the keyword. As several commenters have mentioned, it's generally safer to split your data anyway, especially if it's of an unknown size.

```
String[] sentences = data.split("\\. ");
for (String sentence : sentences) {
    if (sentence.contains("are")) {
        System.out.println(sentence.concat(". "));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. I just want to find sentences with a particular search word in it.
All sentences will end with a "." followed by a space.
But there can be dots which are not followed by a space within the sentences.
This was my requirement.
An example is given in the question itself.
In the example i used the search keyword as "are".

Comment: Yea. That will be a safer option. But it will be better if there is a regex solution for the same. Because i have heard that regex check is very much faster.

Comment: @user2722117 Splitting first will actually give you a **speedup** over the regular expression you're using now. The `split` method uses a *simple* regex to do all the hard work of quickly splitting the input. Once you have all the smaller strings, searching them is very quick. And it is **much** quicker in any case to search small strings one at a time than to attempt to search a very large string with a complicated regular expression with lots of backtracking. [Try the simple option first](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), and then optimize further *only if you need to!*